# Potential memory leak if a tuple of a unique pointer is captured in lambda

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, c++17, clang-tidy, clang-static-analyzer

`clang-tidy` and `scan-build` warn about a potential memory leak in this code:

```cpp
#include <tuple>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    auto lambda = [tuple = std::make_tuple(std::make_unique<int>(42))] {};
}
```

```bash
$ clang-tidy main.cpp -checks="clang*"
1 warning generated.
/foo/main.cpp:7:1: warning: Potential leak of memory pointed to by field '_M_head_impl' [clang-analyzer-cplusplus.NewDeleteLeaks]
}
^
/foo/main.cpp:6:44: note: Calling 'make_unique<int, int>'
    auto lambda = [tuple = std::make_tuple(std::make_unique<int>(42))] {};
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/11/../../../../include/c++/11/bits/unique_ptr.h:962:30: note: Memory is allocated
    { return unique_ptr<_Tp>(new _Tp(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...)); }
                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/foo/main.cpp:6:44: note: Returned allocated memory
    auto lambda = [tuple = std::make_tuple(std::make_unique<int>(42))] {};
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/foo/main.cpp:7:1: note: Potential leak of memory pointed to by field '_M_head_impl'
}
^
```

Is there anything I do not see, or is it a false positive?

---

Environment: clang 13.0.0, gcc 11.3.1.

Compile commands:

```
[
{
  "directory": "/foo",
  "command": "/usr/bin/g++ -std=c++17 /foo/main.cpp",
  "file": "/foo/main.cpp"
}
]
```

Notes: the issue is reproducible with `-std=c++17` and `-std=c++20`, but not with `-std=c++14`.

Comment: The only (possibly) relevant change I can find between C++14 and C++17 is that, in the latter, the `template< class U > unique_ptr( std::auto_ptr<U>&& u )` constructor is removed. [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An unsolved bug in clang-tidy:
https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/55219

It doesn't have anything to do with tuples or smart pointers as seen in the simplified reproduction in this [comment](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/55219#issuecomment-1115904276).

Comment: `struct box` from this example essentially does what smart pointers do, so I would still consider this somewhat related to smart pointers. Otherwise, thanks for the link!

Answer (score 2):

The lambda gets destructed after running out of scope, together with it is capture – and as the tuple is captured by value it gets destructed as well, together with it the smart pointer and thus the object stored there.

Try this to see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <tuple>

struct S
{
    S() { std::cout << "constructed" << std::endl; }
    ~S() { std::cout << "destructed" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    auto lambda = [tuple = std::make_tuple(std::make_unique<S>())] {};
    return 0;
}
```

See on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/d74ojWT5s).

So apparently a false positive...

Comment: When I look at the compiler output I see the call to `make_unique` and `make_tuple` and then I see a call to `~unique_ptr`, `~lambda`, which in turn calls `~tuple`, which then calls `~unique_ptr` (right?) and finally another `~unique_ptr`. So why do I see the destruction of 3 `unique_ptr` here?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Will analyse later, my guess for now is that there are two temporaries involved (from which data had been moved away already)...

Comment: The fact that `~S` is only called once supports that. I thought that `make_unique` creates one of the temporaries and it would be better to do in-place initialization like so: `std::make_tuple<std::unique_ptr<S>>({});` But that produces the same code. There doesn't seem to be a way to emplace into a tuple, I guess because forwarding the constructor args for anything but a one-tuple would be basically impossible and one-tuple is kind of a stupid type.

Comment: So `make_unique` makes a temporary that gets moved into the tuple. That's 2 of the ~unique_ptr` calls. I just don't get where the 3rd comes from. PS: What is the lifetime of the `unique_ptr` temporary used to make the tuple? Does it get it's lifetime extended to the lifetime of `tuple`?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Lifetime of the temporaries should end with the expression they have been created with (descriptively: after passing first semicolon within main). Hm... Destructing the unique_ptr twice on destructing the lambda appears strange.

Comment: Could there be a temporary tuple but inlined so only the destruction of the unique_ptr remains?

Comment: To be considered for the first temporary: We call `make_tuple` which itself accepts classic or rvalue *references* just as does the tuple constructor as well – where to bind these to if we do not produce a temporary? I assume that's why return value optimisation (!) cannot be applied for `make_unique` in this case. Or could a very smart one?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow If that temporary tuple was created while constructing the lambda it should get destructed right within that same expression (first one in main). So if it existed and gets destructed together with the lambda it would need to be created in the lambda's destructor. Rather doubt that, though.

Comment: No, the temporary tuple would get destructed at the end of the expression creating the lambda. Which actually rules it out because the 3rd call to `~unique_ptr` is after `~lambda`. Unless the lifetime is extended for some reason. It's some unique_ptr which lifetime is longer than the lambda.

Comment: [Enabling optimisations](https://godbolt.org/z/qchWvbf5x) the problem seems to have gone: Memory allocated (must be the S; 6), constructor of `S` apparently inlined (12, 32, 34), then destructor of `S` called (36; with outputs at 61, 81, 83), finally memory freed (38) – and in between all yet some exception handling.

Comment: The lambda is optimized away since it is unused. Which then drops the tuple and then the unique_ptr. Only the `S` and `~S` calls remains because of their side effects. That's expected. The question remains where the 3rd `~unique_ptr` call comes from when not optimizing.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Good point... But then [let's use it](https://godbolt.org/z/Krbh38qW3) – haven't analysed deeply yet, but doesn't seem to change much (apart from more exception handling)...

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Oh – did you actually *follow execution* – or just *count occurrences*? Because in the latter case these additional calls should originate from the exception handling...

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/frEje7Kh3 You are right, I missed that there is a "jmp .L11" inbetween the `~lambda` and last `~unique_ptr` skipping the destructor call. So that call is only made when the tuple creation throws an exception as part of the stack unwinding. Mystery solved.